# How to burn BEP20 token on pancakeswap

Tags: solidity, blockchain, binance, pancakeswap

I have BEP20 token with total supply of 1000 tokens. i want to list it on pancake-swap and want to provide initial liquidity of 1000 tokens (all tokens) for 1 BNB. Since i have a burn function in my BEP20 token contract, does calling the burn function(For example if i burn 150 tokens by calling the burn function) will reduce the liquidity on pancakeswap automatically? and this is what the token burn actually is ? I mean would it increase the value of other remaining tokens?

Comment: You cannot burn tokens deposited in the token pool. Those tokens belong to the token pool contract. To burn them you have to remove liquidity from the token pool and then burn them.